Is it possible to connect to wifi from many devices?
Can i connect to the network at the same time from different devices? and who will then get priority (i suppose the first one )? Or, for example, from one device using the linux nmcli utility but with different connection data (ssid, pass)
For example:
nmcli device wifi connect RouterSSID password 12345678

and at the same time run another command with different connection data
nmcli device wifi connect RouterSSID password 99999999


I believe theoretically yes, assuming by different devices you mean the same computer but on different interfaces. You may need multiple NICs (network interface card) to do so though, though I am also unsure. If you do mean different computers though, the answer is yes, multiple computers can connect to the same network.
Also, if you change the SSID you won't be connecting to the same Wi-Fi network, and if you change the password from the correct one you won't be allowed to connect.

Please don't answer off-topic question; that only encourages more of those.
